# the limit behavior of complex integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

$n$ is an nonnegative integer, $a>1$, $$I_n= \oint_{|z|=1} \frac{e^z}{z^{2n}(z^2+a^2)}dz$$

please calculate $$\lim_{n \to +\infty} a^{2n}|I_n|$$

I know when $a>1$, then $f$ has only one singular point $z=0$, but I can't get the residue.

Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Just evaluate $I_n$: using the "coefficient-of" notation,
\begin{align}
I_n&=2\pi i[z^{2n-1}]\frac{e^z}{a^2+z^2}
\\&=2\pi i[z^{2n-1}] \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k!}z^k\right) \left(\sum_{l=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^l}{a^{2l+2}}z^{2l}\right)
\\&=2\pi i\sum_{j=1}^n\frac1{(2j-1)!}\frac{(-1)^{n-j}}{a^{2(n-j)+2}}
\\&=\frac{2\pi i(-1)^n}{a^{2n+1}}\sum_{j=1}^n(-1)^j\frac{a^{2j-1}}{(2j-1)!}.
\end{align}

Now the limit is easily seen to be $\color{blue}{(2\pi/a)|\sin a|}$.